# Datatables dropdowns issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm using this code trying to implement dropdowns for all columns in jQuery-Datatables [like in this example](https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html).

```
var table = $('#myTable').DataTable({
        dom: 'lfBrtip',
        buttons: [
        {
            extend: 'copy',
            footer: true
        },
        {
            extend: 'csv',
            footer: true
        },
        {
            extend: 'excel',
            footer: true
        },
        {
            extend: 'pdf',
            footer: true
        }
    ],
        initComplete: function () {
        this.api().columns().every( function () {
            var column = this;
            var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
                .appendTo( $(column.header()))
                .on( 'change', function () {
                    var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                        $(this).val()
                    );

                    column
                        .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                        .draw();
                } );

            column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
            } );
        } );
.......
    }
```

Imediately there are problems with this as u can see in the pictures:

**1. Clicking the dropdowns makes the columns sort and i don't want that.**
[image]

**2. The buttons get inserted in the export.**
[image]

What am i doing wrong or how can i correct it? Maybe a workaround?

---

**Updated with buttons:[ ]**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's a better way to achieve this but the following is what I've came up with.

You may want to look at [buttons.exportData()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/buttons.exportData()) api reference. I've used the `format` option in order to format the header columns as follows:

```
var buttonExp = {
  exportOptions: {
    format: {
      header: function ( data, column, row ) {
        return header[column]; //header is the array I used to store header texts
      }
    }
  }
};
```

You may want to format the `data` argument to get the text of the header and strip the html but this one looks cleaner. Then you need to store the header texts in an array like this

```
var header = [];
header.push("Column Header 1");
header.push("Column Header 2");
header.push("Column Header N");
```

Finally, bind the button to an element on page as follows

```
new $.fn.dataTable.Buttons( table, {
        "buttons": [$.extend( true, {}, buttonExp, {
        extend: 'excelHtml5'
    })]
});     

table.buttons(0,null).containers().appendTo('.container');
```

Here is the **[demo](http://live.datatables.net/jevagolo/1/edit)** page.

**EDIT**

The demo you have provided was quite close to solving the export issue. But you were not binding the button to dom. Thus were not able to see the button on page.

I have made a small modification on your button list by replacing

```
{
    extend: 'excel',
    footer: true
},
```

with

```
$.extend(true, {}, buttonExp, {
  extend: 'excelHtml5'
}),
```

Also, I have removed the following code, since it was no longer needed.

```
new $.fn.dataTable.Buttons(table, {
    "buttons": [$.extend(true, {}, buttonExp, {
        extend: 'excelHtml5'
    })]
});
```

Here is the updated version of your **[demo](http://live.datatables.net/jevagolo/8/edit)**.

Comment: I'm staring at it for 20 minutes ...aaaand i must say i have no clue of what is this supposed to do or how i could implement it. I'm sory, i am new to datatables and new to javascript.

Comment: you can add the code parts right after your code above and see if it works.

Comment: I have added a demo page link to the answer. Simply click on "Excel" button at the end of the page.

Comment: I gave it a fast test, and it looks like that solves the export problem. I'm looking into the code right now. Do u have any solution to stop reordering when u click on the dropdown?

Comment: Kindly see the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13024277/jquery-datatable-dropdown-filter-in-header-sorts Edit: I don't think you need that line by the way `this.innerHTML = fnCreateSelect( oTable.fnGetColumnData(i) );`

Comment: actually you only need this version -> `$("thead th").each( function ( i ) {
    $('select', this).click( function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    } );
  });`

Comment: I updated the code with the buttons:[ ] that i use. I can't get your export button to show up on my page. Is there any way to get your code working with my export buttons or should i create a new question for this?

Comment: are you sure you're binding the button to an element on page and not getting any errors in console? for instance -> `table.buttons(0,null).containers().appendTo('.container');` binds the button to a `div` element with the class `container`. i would suggest adding this markup under the table -> `<div class='container'></div>` and leave the rest of the code as it is. you should be able to see the excel button then. if not, launch a demo page with your entire code in it -> [link](http://live.datatables.net/)

Comment: see the updated answer please. you were quite close by the way.

Comment: Thank you so much for having patience with me! Tested export for csv and pdf and they all work!

Answer (score 0):

try below one

> $(select).children('option').append(......)

instead of

> select.append(

Comment: That has a even weirder effect: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4nUvzf87W8KM2U2ZFBlQkNKZDA/view